# Javascript module parttern ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, design-patterns

I am learning javascript design patterns. So am converting my rough jquery code into cleaner module pattern. The question is, how will i call a click event after ajax has loaded in module pattern (Object literal). I used to solve it using $(document).ajaxcomplete(callback).

here is the working supergetti code

```js
$('.meidaBtn, #media_load_btn').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.media').show(500);

  $('#mediaBox').html('Loading...');
  var link = location.origin + '/dashboard/media';

  $.ajax({
    url: link
  }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
    $('#mediaBox').html(data); // display data

    // Click through
    $('.imageBox img').bind('click', function() {
      var src = $(this).attr('src');
      var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
      src = src.replace('tumbnail_', '');

      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt + '">');
      $('.media').hide();
    });
  });

});
```

Here is the javascript module pattern / object literal

```js
var mediaPlugin = {
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  // Cache Dom 
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.baseUrl = location.origin + '/dashboard/media';

    this.$button = $('.meidaBtn, #media_load_btn');
    this.$media = $('.media');
    this.$mediaBox = $('#mediaBox');
    this.$imageBox = $('.imageBox img');
  },

  // Bind Events
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$button.on('click', this.render.bind(this));
    this.$imageBox.on('click', this.addImage.bind(this));
  },

  // Show Data
  render: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$media.show(500);
    this.loadData();
  },

  // Load the data
  loadData: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: this.baseUrl,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(that.$mediaBox);
        that.$mediaBox.html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("An error occored!");
      },
      complete: function() {
        // console.log("I am now complete");
        // that.loadMore();
      }
    });
  },

  // Add Image
  addImage: function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    src = src.replace('tumbnail_', '');

    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt + '">');
    this.$media.hide();
  }
};

mediaPlugin.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured how to get this code working. I used jquery .delegate() and i now work like magic. Below is the working code. thanks @abc123 for stoping by.

```
var media = (function(){
// Cache dom
var baseUrl = location.origin+'/dashboard/media';

var $button = $('.meidaBtn, #media_load_btn');
var $media = $('.media');
var $mediaBox = $('#mediaBox');
var $imageBox = $mediaBox.find('img');

var options = { 
    url: baseUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        $mediaBox.html(data); 
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("An error occored!");
    },
    complete: function(){
        // console.log("I am now complete");
        // that.loadMore();
    }
};

// Bind Events
$button.on('click', _render);
$mediaBox.delegate('.imageBox', 'click', _addImage);

function _render(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $media.show(500);
    _loadData();
}

// Load images
function _loadData(){
    $.ajax(options);
}

// Add Images 
function _addImage(){
    img = $(this).find('img');

    console.log(img.attr('src')); // This should display the image url
}
```

})();

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but note that `delegate()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead (unless you have to use an older version of jQuery for some reason.)

Comment: I have been trying .on() but It wasn't functioning until i tried .delegate(). I will still try to make .on() work. Thanks for your time @MattBrowne

Comment: @MattBrowne finally used .on() and it worked. I guess that when it wasn't working i was implementing it in a wring way. I finally consulted the jquery manual. Thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

The method provided below adds a simple property to the object which is used as a delegate/callback.  You simply point your function to it and then it is called automatically since it is called in the complete event.

```js
var mediaPlugin = {
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  // Cache Dom 
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.baseUrl = location.origin + '/dashboard/media';

    this.$button = $('.meidaBtn, #media_load_btn');
    this.$media = $('.media');
    this.$mediaBox = $('#mediaBox');
    this.$imageBox = $('.imageBox img');
  },

  // Bind Events
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.$button.on('click', this.render.bind(this));
    this.$imageBox.on('click', this.addImage.bind(this));
  },

  // Show Data
  render: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$media.show(500);
    this.loadData();
  },

  loadDataComplete: function() {},
  
  // Load the data
  loadData: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: this.baseUrl,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(that.$mediaBox);
        that.$mediaBox.html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("An error occored!");
      },
      complete: function() {
        // console.log("I am now complete");
        // that.loadMore();
        that.loadDataComplete();
      }
    });
  },
  
  // Add Image
  addImage: function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    src = src.replace('tumbnail_', '');

    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt + '">');
    this.$media.hide();
  }
};

var myCompleteFunction = function myCompleteFunction() {}
mediaPlugin.init();
mediaPlugin.loadDataComplete = myCompleteFunction;
mediaPlugin.loadData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```